# How to POST dynamic input tags in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I am facing a serious dilemma, and wondering how this would be possible. I have a form built in codeigniter framework. At the end of the form is an input tag which takes a number and appends a new form with exact rows of input tags as the value of the last input tag. I have done this using javascript, code is

```
$('#formName9').on('change', function() {
       var selected = $(this).val();
       $('#subForm').empty();
       $("#subForm").append('<table border="" style="border:none; background:#f2f2f1; margin-bottom:10px; border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 25px; box-shadow: 9px 4px 8px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">            <tr>              <td style="text-align: center; width: 30px; border-width: 0px;"><img src="<?php echo  base_url(); ?>assets/img/icon_house.png" ></td>              <td style="text-align: center; border-width: 0px;"><img src="<?php echo  base_url(); ?>assets/img/table_divider.png" /></td>              <td style="text-align: center; width: 200px; border-width: 0px;"><strong>Unit Name</strong></td>              <td style="text-align: center; border-width: 0px;"><img src="<?php echo  base_url(); ?>assets/img/table_divider.png" /></td>              <td style="text-align: center; width: 250px; border-width: 0px;" ><strong>Owner Name</strong></td>              <td style="text-align: center; border-width: 0px;"><img src="<?php echo  base_url(); ?>assets/img/table_divider.png" /></td>              <td style="text-align: center;width: 150px; border-width: 0px;"><strong>Owner Salutation</strong></td> </tr> </table>');
       for (var i=1; i<=selected; i++) {
           $('#subForm').append('<div style="float: left; padding-left: 13px; padding-right: 12px; padding-top: 7px; margin-top: 0px;">'+i+'</div><input type="text" name="unitName" id="unitName'+i+'" style="width:189px;" required /><input type="text" name="ownerName'+i+'" id="ownerName'+i+'" style="width:241px;" /><input type="text" name="salutation'+i+'" id="salutation'+i+'" style="width:137px;" /><br />');
       }
    });
```

you can see i have used different naming conventions for all the appended tags according to the loop.

Now these values need to be posted in order for the PHP[SERVER] to do further work, but how will i post these dynamic values? i have tried to the following, but this just hangs my local server and doesn't go any further

```
$ownerName = array();
                    for ($i=0; $i<=$blockUnits ; $i+1) { 
                        $ownerName[$i] = "ownerName".$i;
                        $this->input->post('ownerName[$i]');
                    }
```

Comment: Some answers would be appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

i think it should be easier if you post your value in array ...

example..

```
 <input type="text" name="ownerName[]" id="ownerName'+i+'" style="width:241px;" />
```

and loop it in controller...

```
foreach($this->input->post('ownerName') as test){
.....
}
```

similar for others

Comment: in valid argument supplied to foreach

Comment: that means your posted value for input ownerName is empty...make sure you are posting the values.. if not then you can use `is_array()` check before the loop

Comment: i have written values in the input tags and i have used is_array check, this gives me false meaning it is not an array

Comment: but if you post your input name as array `name="ownerName[]"` here notice the `[]` this will post the all the input calues for ownerName in array.. have you tried this ??

Comment: Sounds like it's your form that's screwing up and not the individual inputs. If you're getting an invalid foreach that means the array is empty and not posting. Double check the layout of the form, make sure you have the open and close tags right and the submit inside them.

Comment: Listen to me carefully:
$this->input->post('ownerName');
is not working, everything else is fine

Answer (score 1):

While adding new input text boxes, give names for those fields as given below.

For example if user wants to add 5 fields, then the output will become something like

```
<input type="text" name="ownerName[]" />
<input type="text" name="ownerName[]" />
<input type="text" name="ownerName[]" />
<input type="text" name="ownerName[]" />
<input type="text" name="ownerName[]" />
```

Then in PHP you can get values of these fields like

```
$ownerNames = $_POST['ownerName'];

foreach( $ownerNames as $ownerName ) {
    echo "Owner Name is : " . $ownerName;
}
```

As you are trying in CodeIgniter, the code will look something like this (getting post variable)

```
$ownerNames = $this->input->post('ownerName');

foreach( $ownerNames as $ownerName ) {
    echo "Owner Name is : " . $ownerName;
}
```

Comment: the server says invalid argument supplied for foreach

Comment: You are getting ownerNames in CodeIgniter style only. Right?

Comment: i have done some debugging and found that all the arrays are empty, so nothing is posted, and in reply to your question above: if you are referring to view file than no as you can see i have appended the tags using javascript and they are html tags not codeignter...